# How to gather specific tokens to send push notifications to specific devices

Tags: typescript, firebase, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

This is where I filter the user's contacts, I do this to only get the user's contacts and if they have an account created, then they will show up on your screen. (There's more to this, but this is just to be more visual)

```
 List<PhonesContacts> phoneContacts = snapshot.data;
              List myContacts = [];
              
              for (var j = 0; j < phoneContacts.length; j++) {
                myContacts.contains(phoneContacts[j])
                 ? null
                 : myContacts.add(phoneContacts[j]);

              }
```

`My Question:` Will I need to do the same thing above in the back end(cloud functions) to filter the user's tokens so I can then only send the notifications to your contacts? OR is there a way that I can communicate from the front end to the backend? That way I can just send *myContacts* array to the backend, then all I simply need to do is filter the tokens.

Here is what I am doing for cloud functions, I understand that what I have at the moment gets everybody's tokens and sends a notification to everybody's device. So again, the issue, how to only send notifications to the users that are only showing on your screen(which are your contacts because I filtered them in the front end)

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();
const fcm = admin.messaging();


export const sendToDevice = functions.firestore
  .document('stat/{statId}')
  .onUpdate(async change => {


   const data = change.after.data();

   const currentUser = await db 
      .collection("profile")   
      .doc(data.uid)         
      .get();

   const name = currentUser.get("name");

   const querySnapshot = await db
      .collection('tokens')
      .get();
    
   /* Somewhere here I would access their contacts and filter it, then get their tokens and put it in the array OR if I can, I would just send the already filtered contacts I did in the front end, then just put the tokens in the array */

    const tokens = querySnapshot.docs.map(snap => snap.data().token);


    const payload: admin.messaging.MessagingPayload = {
      notification: {
        title: name,
        body: data.stat,
        click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'
      },
      data: {
         click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
         title: name,
         body: data.stat
      }
    };

    return fcm.sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
  });
```

Comment: I'm having problems understanding what the problem is here.

Comment: I added a `question` section @DougStevenson

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "filter the contacts in the back end".  You haven't said anything about your tokens collection that would be helpful.

Comment: Well I am using the flutter package https://pub.dev/packages/contacts_service#-readme-tab- In my app, I have filtered the user's contacts, so that means only their contacts will be showing on the main screen(If they have an account created). I asked if I am going to have to do it again in the back end, then filter the tokens, if not, then can I somehow do it by communicating from the front end to the back end?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a package that actually allows you to communicate from the front end to the back end. Using the cloud_functions flutter package https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_functions